# Meta Tag Cleanup

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

There was a big push to clean up a lot of the main site tags, but the meta tags are in a bad state aswell. I'm finding a lot of overlap, maybe a moderator can take a look at these?

[acceptable-questions](/questions/tagged/acceptable-questions) → [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics)

[close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) → [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions)

[editing](/questions/tagged/editing) → [editor](/questions/tagged/editor)

[tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) → [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

[voting](/questions/tagged/voting) → [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)

I'm also not sure what [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) is meant to be

[or vice versa for most things]

There's a couple more that are a bit redundant, but those were the main ones I saw

Comment: [meta-tag:tagging] is already syn'd to [meta-tag:tags] per this post: [(link)](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/719/1908). Regarding that and also `voting`/`votes`, related [meta.se] feature request: [(link)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234473/224428). [meta-tag:specific-question] is typically used (at least on other sites) for things like "why was this particular question closed?" or "should we deem this particular question off-topic?".

Comment: [meta-tag:editor] should be for questions about the Markdown editor (I've added a wiki excerpt), while [meta-tag:editing] should be for questions about the task of editing itself (e.g. when do I edit; is this edit appropriate; etc.). They probably shouldn't be syn'd.

Comment: [meta-tag:scope] should also be syn'd to [meta-tag:allowed-topics] (or vice versa - "scope" is a default tag on child metas, but it's a terrible name for a tag, so I favor "allowed-questions" anyway).

Comment: cool that clears up a couple of em :)